# Claims to windows token service impersonated token

Tags: sharepoint, impersonation, claims, c2wts

I have a claims based SharePoint 2010 website where I need to call out to a back end non-claims aware system (K2 blackpearl).

So to achieve this I am attempting to use the claims to windows token service to impersonate the user as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517278.aspx)

Now when calling the c2wts using a user UPN to convert to a claim using the following code:

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = null;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
delegate()
{
windowsIdentity = S4UClient.UpnLogon("user@domain.com");
});
```

Now when I impersonate that windowsIdentity.ImpersonationLevel is Identification rather than Impersonate

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext c = windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
Debug.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel); // returns Identification
ConnectToK2();
c.Undo();
}
```

This I think is what is causing the problem as when trying to call off to the service using the token it is failing.  The article mentioned above talks about getting a Impersonated token back but I am unable to do this.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get impersonation level equal to impersonation, set impersonation in your web.config to false:

```
    <identity impersonate="false" />
```

Also try not to perform impersonation inside "SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges" since this way you are performing impersonation twice - first as a webapplication pool account (this is what RunWithElevatedPriviliges is causing) and then with your manual impersonation using token from c2wts.